# Asp.Net Register Global Custom Filter Not Having [ChildAactionOnly] attribute

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, action-filter

I know how to Register Global filter that applies all actions with:

```
protected void Application_Start(){
    GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new MySweetCustomFiAttribute());
}
```

But instead, I need to register `MySweetCustomFilterAttribute` to actions not having (or having) `[ChildActionOnly]` attribute.

```
    // Register MySweetCustomFilterAttribute
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
       return View();
    }

   // Do not register MySweetCustomFilterAttribute
   [ChildActionOnly]
   public ActionResult MySweetChildAction()
    {
      ...
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put a bypass into your [MySweetCustomFiAttribute] to return if the action is decorated with [ChildActionOnly]. Like this:

```cs
if(filterContext.ActionDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(ChildActionOnlyAttribute), false))
    return;
```

Comment: Thanks your method. I inspired by it and implemented a work around like you.  `ActionDescriptor` does not work OnResultExecut(ed|ing)` methods. 
`var isChild = filterContext.IsChildAction;` is more straigh-forward.

Answer (score 0):

Here the complete work-around with the help of @pedro-benevides

```
namespace tv2web.Filters{
    public class MainModelFixAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute {
        protected bool IsChild(ControllerContext filterContext) {
            return filterContext.IsChildAction;
        }

    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)  {
        if (IsChild(filterContext)) return;

        filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.mainModel = filterContext.Controller.ViewData.Model;
    }

    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext) {
        if (IsChild(filterContext)) return;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) {
        if (IsChild(filterContext)) return;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext) {
        if (IsChild(filterContext)) return;
    }


}
```

}